# R merge error: output filled of 'NA' for large data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, na

I am trying to use the merge function of R on a large dataset:

- First data frame is Dates called Dates_test (dim = 7472 x 1)
- Second data frame are Dates and Values called Histo_test (dim = 5064 x 501). Dates here are a subset of first data frame. With more that 604,000 numeric values.

The Dates column of both data frames is called "dates". I use the merge function as below:

```
test_test <- merge(x = Dates_test, y = Histo_test, by = "dates", all.x = TRUE)
```

and it returns a data frame of 7472 row by 501 columns, but filled with 'NA'. None of the Histo_test data is in test_test.

I tried to do the same on a smaller set of data and it worked fine. Therefore, I think the error might comes from the size of the tables.

See below the full code:

```
Histo_test <- read.table(Name_test[1], fill = TRUE,header=TRUE, sep=",")
Dates_test <- read.table(Name_test[2], fill = TRUE,header=TRUE, sep=",")
test_test <- merge(x = Dates_test, y = Histo_test, by = "dates", all.x = TRUE)
```

And output filled of 'NA':

```
> sum(is.numeric(test_test))
[1] 0
> sum(is.na(test_test))
[1] 3736000
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try to use the join instead of merge from the package plyr ?

```
test_test <- merge(Dates_test, Histo_test, by = "dates", type = "left")
```

Comment: It makes me think that the dates in both dataframe are not the same. Can you check this ?

Comment: I am sure the dates from Histo_test is a subset of Dates_test. I'd be more than happy to send you the CSVs.

Comment: then send me your csv =)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe you can put it in your drive (google or microsoft) and send me the link ?

Comment: What i'm seeing is that first, dates columns in Histo is named Timestamp, and the other thing is that your dates don't have the same format, one is yyyy-mm-dd and the other dd/mm/yyyy so yous must have the same format using this `Histo_test$dates <- strptime(as.character( Histo_test$dates), "%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: Ah yes sorry I removed first row and rename first column of Histo (but didn't mentioned it here). regarding the format I will investigate.

Comment: Format was the issue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution but it's hard to tell without your data. Here is a solution using `dplyr`. If this is what you're after, try this with your own data.

```
library(dplyr)

Dates_test <- data.frame(dates = seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"),as.Date("2017-12-31"),by="day"))
Histo_test <- data.frame(dates = seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"),as.Date("2017-12-31"),by="month"),
                         Values =1:12,
                         Values2=letters[1:12])

Output <- left_join(Dates_test,Histo_test,by="dates")

head(Output)
```

outputs:

```
       dates Values Values2
1 2017-01-01      1       a
2 2017-01-02     NA    <NA>
3 2017-01-03     NA    <NA>
4 2017-01-04     NA    <NA>
5 2017-01-05     NA    <NA>
6 2017-01-06     NA    <NA>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my code using your csvs

```
Dates_test <- read.csv("merge_issue_dates.csv")
Dates_test$dates <- as.Date(Dates_test$dates)

Hist_dates <- read.csv("merge_issue.csv",)
Hist_dates$dates <- as.Date(Hist_dates$Timestamp,format="%d/%m/%Y")
Output <- left_join(Dates_test,Hist_dates,by="dates")
```

The issues were, inconsitent date format (fixed with `as.Date()` and your date colum in `merge_issue.csv` was called `Timestamp`

Comment: Hi, I have the same result with dplyr. Data filled of 'NA'.
Is there a way to attach csv files in stackoverflow?

Comment: With these data, `merge(Dates_test, Histo_test, by="dates")` outputs a 12 row df since argument `all` defaults to `FALSE`. There must be something else going on.

Comment: @Pierre If this isn't working, i think there must be another issue with your dataset as I've just tried my example with 70000 rows and it worked fine.

Comment: I checked my data via Excel. I can confirm that the dates of Histo_test are all in Dates_test. The rest of Histo_test are numeric and empty cells.

Comment: @Pierre i've added code using your csvs to fix your issue